# Drush Make for a custom module hosted at github

Tags: version-control, drush

I am trying to fetch a custom module versioned at github.com via drush make, but I get

```
Could not retrieve version information for custom_migration 
Non-existent project type  on project techarena_migration
```

My drush make file section for the custom module is the following:

```
projects[custom_migration][subdir] = "custom"
projects[custom_migration][type] = "module"
projects[custom_migration][download][type] = "git"
projects[custom_migration][download][url]="git@github.com:qed42/custom_migration.git"
```

I also tried giving the branch parameter, but no change

```
projects[custom_migration][download][branch] = "master"
```

This is a private repository, could it be that?

**Update:** I am so sorry, I was using the wrong makefile. Sorry to have wasted your time. I am not sure if I should close the question?

P.S git:// doesn't work with private repo on github, git@github.com does!!

Comment: Have you tried running the make command with --debug? Also, is this the only error you are getting? I've seen drush make confuse itself if several projects are getting errors, and attribute an error incorrectly.

Comment: Should I close the question given that I found out that I was using the wrong makefile :(

Comment: No, I'd suggest you write what you found as an answer and then accept that, so that the question is marked as fixed. Also try to explain how you found it out and other information that might be valuable to someone that comes to this question from google or so.

Comment: I was searching for a solution to this type of problem, and found it here. The specific solution is that `projects[custom_migration][type] = "module"` needs to be in the make file when using a custom module.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [documentation](http://drupalcode.org/project/drush_make.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/6.x-2.x:/README.txt), you have to write the download url line this way:

```
projects[mytheme][download][url] = "git://github.com/jane_doe/mytheme.git"
```

Comment: Doesn't matter if I do git:// or https:// (the one shown by github as an alternate clone url) but as far as I know git@<gitserver> works!

Comment: I have drush make working using both forms (in the same make file).

Comment: I am so sorry, I was using the wrong makefile. Sorry to have wasted your time.

Answer (score 2):

> This is a private repository, could it
>   be that?

Can you do `git clone git@github.com:qed42/custom_migration.git` from the same shell that you are running drush make from?

You may need to add a new public key to be able to access the repo.

Comment: Yep, can do that!! git clone works fine from shell, my ssh keys are properly setup. I am wondering if its coz of private repo, should not be.. have u ever before cloned/checked out private repo from drush make?

Comment: Yes private repos work fine for me, so long as the ssh keys are set up properly.

Comment: I am so sorry, I was using the wrong makefile. Sorry to have wasted your time.

Answer (score 1):

In order for drush to be able to checkout the code, it must be available for the terminal running the make file. So if you have an SSH key to the repo, that will work, but you can't checkout if you need to login to perform the checkout.

Also the link should like Drupol describes be formatted like the doc:

```
projects[mytheme][download][url] = "git://github.com/jane_doe/mytheme.git"
```

Comment: Not sure what u mean? I can do git clone <private repo url> from the shell, my ssh keys are properly setup. Also I have tried changing the url format to both git:// and https:// ... I am wondering why does it complain about the version of the project.

Comment: I am so sorry, I was using the wrong makefile. Sorry to have wasted your time.

Comment: It happens, don't worry about it.