# Drush Make removes .git folders

Tags: version-control, drush

After a [silly feeling with drush make and github](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3821/drush-make-for-a-custom-module-hosted-at-github) I found out that all the .git folders (used by git to record history, config, origin location etc ) were removed by drush make and I have heard about this before but didn't come across myself as I was not maintaining the make files.

Specifically drush make removes the .git folder and u can see that if u run it with --debug option

```
Executing: rm -rf '/tmp/drush_make_tmp_1305733094/__git__/__build__/.git'
```

In my make file I am fetching 4 things from git repo because I wish to track development on them, 2 of them are my custom components ( 1 custom module and 1 feature which records all the config) and the other drupal core and media module due to high volume of fixes they receive. The whole purpose seems defeated if I can't have respective .git folders but I am also sure there is a way as others are using drush make with git but couldn't find in my quick search.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pass the "--working-copy" switch to Drush Make.

```
drush make --working-copy site.make
```

Comment: If you'd like per-project control over this, you can add to the make file: `projects[project_name][options][working-copy] = TRUE`

Answer (score 7):

And if you're using YAML for your make file, the following will allow you to preserve the .git repository info:

```
projects:

  drupal:
    type: core
    version: 8.0.x
    download:
      working-copy: true
```

And further, if you don't want drush to add in extra information to projects' .info files, make sure you use the `--no-gitinfofile` option when running `drush make`.

Answer (score 3):

On project by project basis, in a make file you can add the option like this

```
projects[project_name][download][type] = git
projects[project_name][download][url] = ssh://git@...etc
projects[project_name][options][working-copy] = TRUE
```

Comment: This is not correct; Andy's comment above actually works. You have to use the options array, not the download array, to fetch the working copy.